# GitHub actions, how can I get jobs to run only within folders that contain code changes?

Tags: github-actions

GitHub actions, how can I get jobs to run only within folders that contain code changes?

I have a monorepo that sores a number of projects where the folder structure will not be identical or consistent.

I would like to run a number of GitHub Actions in such a way so that they only execute within the changed folder.

my sanitised code looks like

```
jobs:
  format:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Update release docs
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: tf_docs
        uses: Dirrk/terraform-docs@v1.0.8
        with:
          tf_docs_working_dir: .
      - name: create_int_readme
        uses: mja/intreadme@v1.0.0
        with:
          scan_folder: .
      - name: update_perms
        uses: mja/update_perma@v1.0.0
        with:
          folder: .
```

I thought that by setting:

```
    paths:
    - "**/*"
```

That it would recursively scan folders for changes and by setting the various folder params to be. it would pick up on the current working folder.   However, everything runs from the root folder and outputs results there, rather than the folders that contained the actual changes.

I did think about somehow setting an environment variable to contain the value of the paths that have changed, in turn, and then passing that value to the jobs but the.  But the logic escapes me.

So how can I get jobs to run only within folders that contain code changes?

Comment: You can try this: `/**/*`

Comment: That has the same effect - the jobs run in the root folder and output their results in the root folder.   What I am trying to achieve is to get the jobs to jobs to run in whatever sub folder(s) have changed and output the result's into that same folder(s)